# Issue with =Unique

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hopefully this is pretty straightforward, I'm using `=UNIQUE(TOCOL(B5:W183,3))` to pick up supplier names to then go on and use `=SUMIF(B4:U183,D190,C4:C183)` D190 would be the first cell that the first Formula puts a name in to, but I cant seem to figure out how to get the =Unique formula to ignore Numbers and only pick up text, the Numbers and Text are not in the same cell, but they are in the same range as that cant be avoided.

I've tried using =Sort with t but that makes it only put out a single supplier before it stops looking

Comment: You can filter the TOCOL array using ISNUMBER. Your SUMIF formula isn't going to work as the ranges should be the same size and shape.

Comment: @Rory Thanks for the reply, I've changed the SumIF range to match the Unique, i'm having trouble figuring out where the IsNumber needs to go though, I'm fairly new to Formulas as a whole, do you have any Recommendations on where to learn how to Order functions when they're in 1 formula?

Comment: Do you have the `LET` function available?

Comment: It looks like i do have =LET as a function, although I've never used it

Comment: In that case, try something like: `=LET(data,TOCOL(B5:W183,3),UNIQUE(FILTER(data,ISTEXT(data))))`

Comment: Wow that actually worked perfectly, thank you so much, I've got so much to learn about Excel its ridiculous haha

Comment: Hmmm now how do i mark it as answered by you

Comment: I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter for only text items like this:

```
=LET(data,TOCOL(B5:W183,3),UNIQUE(FILTER(data,ISTEXT(data))))
```